# How do you protect solar panels for storage during house rebuild?

Tags: solar-panels

I am in the process of preparing to demolish my house so I can rebuild. We are taking the solar panels off the roof and plan to put them back on to the new house. Does anyone know the best way to store them in the meantime? Would heavy duty bubble wrap and being stacked in a corner of a garage be appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

Stacking the panels on top of each other should be fine, but I would not suggest stacking all off them on top of each other as the bottom one will have to bear tremendous weight and might warp it.

Try and place wooden battens (for air flow to stop moisture from being trapped and help displace weight evenly to the next panel using a soft surface) between panels on the same frame that they were mounted to the roof. The frame is load bearing and will handle weight on top of it and disperse weight downwards to the next panel.

You do not have to cover each one in bubble wrap. Just stack em using batons(bareing in mind weight) and then cover the entire stack in foil and possibly some polystyrene and or bubble wrap on the corners and top to prevent shock damage in case something hits or falls on it.. you never know.

Some panels you can stack ontop of each other with no problem as they have a robust frame that supports all the weight.

Exercise some common sense in how to stack them. Make sure they are level and aligned. check on them every now and again during storage phase in case the weight makes something give in.

Answer (score 3):

PV modules with frames can be stacked quite high when the frames are all aligned. This keeps the weight off the glass and is how framed modules are stacked on pallets for shipment. You really don't need battens or bubble wrap to protect the glass because the frames keep the glass from touching neighboring modules or the floor. But you can put cardboard in between the modules to keep grit from scratching up the frames.

It is unusual to see frameless modules in residential installations, but if that's what you have, you can stand them up vertically with cardboard in between.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but based on what I've see and common knowledge, your idea is good. Wrap them in either heavy duty bubble wrap or use styrofoam in between them and stack them vertically. Stacked one on top of each other would present a higher chance of breaking under weight as well as a larger horizontal surface exposed to the working environment.

Answer (score 0):

Stack them vertically on their sides. Easier to get to, easy to move. No weight bearing.